# What does the minNumObj parameter do in J48 classifier? WEKA

Tags: testing, weka

From the notes in Weka, it says that minNumObj controls the minimum number of instances per leaf. However, using the value of minNumObj=3, Weka produces the tree

```
Scheme:weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -U -M 3

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

J48 unpruned tree
------------------

pension = none: bad (8.0)
pension = ret_allw: bad (3.0/1.0)
pension = empl_contr
|   wage increase first year = low: bad (3.0)
|   wage increase first year = medium: good (3.0)
|   wage increase first year = high: good (0.0)
|   wage increase first year = unknown: good (1.0)
pension = unknown
|   longterm disability assistance = yes: good (4.0)
|   longterm disability assistance = no: bad (1.0)
|   longterm disability assistance = unknown: good (17.0)

Number of Leaves  :     9

Size of the tree :  12
```

which has a few leaves with only 1 instance. How can this happen, given that minNumObj is 3? What is this setting actually controlling?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the minimum instances per leaf guarantees that at each split, at least 2 of the branches (but not necessarily more than 2) will have the minimum number of instances.

This is a sensible design. Consider an extreme case where each node has up to 10 different branches. It would require the parent node to have at least 10 times the minimum number of instances per leaf to branch! Given that the data is likely to be highly unevenly distributed among branches, we're probably more looking in the order of 50 times.

Another way to look at it is that branches is a way to separate out data. Separating one instance from 100 instances doesn't give you much information, so you set a minimum amount of separation. However, if you have a node with four branches, and two of them end up with 0 instances, the other two with 50 each, the branching still produced information.

So in one sentence, the minimum number of instances per leaf is better thought of as "the minimum amount of data separation per branching", in the case of multiway trees.